# How to change the intellij auto complete suggestion for kotlin code

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a design like this

```
fun config(action: ParentConfig.() -> Unit) {
    TODO()
}

interface ParentConfig {

    fun p1(value: String)

    fun p2(value: String)

    fun child(action: ChildConfig.() -> Unit)
}

interface ChildConfig {

    fun c1(value: String)

    fun c2(value: String)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    config {
        p1("Welcome!")
        p2("dear")
        child {
            c1("Tim")
            c2("Cook")
            // Only c1 and c2 are expected here, but I DON'T hope intellij give the suggestion about p1 or p2 even if they are allowed to be used here by kotlin.
        }
    }
}
```

I hope only c1 and c2 can be used in the scope of child object configuration, but p1 and p2 can also be used here in kotlin language so that intellij give the suggestion like this

[image]

I cannot find any annotations that can help me in the package "org.intellij.lang.annotations", Is there any intellij annotations to disable p1 and p2 in this suggestion menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DSL markers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html#scope-control-dslmarker), they're specifically designed to properly control DSL scopes. You can introduce your own marker, e.g.:

```
@DslMarker
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class ConfigMarker
```

And annotate your DSL entities:

```
@ConfigMarker
interface ParentConfig {
  ...
}

@ConfigMarker
interface ChildConfig {
  ...
}
```

The compiler will then prevent you from calling methods on an implicit receiver in the wrong scope:

[image]